# How to fix encoding - curly apostrophe appears as ‰Ûª

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have a text-file in which all the ASCII characters appear correctly but some others do not. In particular there is this word:

```
don‰Ûªt
```

In hex the bytes are `64 6f 6e 89 db aa 74`. Obviously, it is almost certain that `‰Ûª` should be a curly apostrophe, probably [U+02BC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2bc/index.htm), [U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), or [U+0092](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0092/index.htm). [**Edited to add:** Based on copying the correct apostrophe from a PDF that contains the same text, I am now reasonably sure it is [U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).]

[This webpage](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) says

> If a sequence of bits doesn't make sense (to a human) in any encoding, the document has mostly likely been converted incorrectly at some point. ... If a document has been misinterpreted and converted to a different encoding, it's broken. Trying to "repair" it may or may not be successful, usually it isn't. Any manual bit-shifting or other encoding voodoo is mostly that, voodoo.

But surely I ought to be able to work out what happened to my file, given that I know the bytes and I know what character they are supposed to mean. Can anyone tell me how to work out how the file became corrupted, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Can anyone tell me how to work out how the file became corrupted, ...**

I can't, but maybe you'll get lucky.

Given a scrambled configuration of a Rubik's cube it is very easy to work out a set of moves to return it to the starting state. It is usually impossible to work out which moves were used to arrive at the scrambled state - because the number of possible sequences of moves is vast.

Your problem is similar. Partly because you give no clues about platforms, locales and tools that may have been used to create this text file.

0x89 is not a valid first-byte for a three-byte UTF8 encoding of a character. 0xDBAA is Arabic empty centre low stop. Which is of course implausible.
Perhaps UTF8 has been misinterpreted as some 8-bit encoding and then saved as a different 8-bit encoding. If the file has been near Japan you might throw some misuses of JIS, Shift-JIS and EUC into the mix.

There are maybe a dozen plausible Unicode characters and probably a greater number of plausible 8-bit and 16-bit encodings. That's too many permutations to try manually. If it was important enough, I'd maybe write code to try all permutations of starting character plus two scramblings and see if any arrive at 0x89DBAA.

Statistically I'd expect the most likely scenario is something almost but not quite entirely unlike:

1. Create a UTF8 text file without BOM (as Unicode consortium recommend).
2. Read that file using MS-Windows Notepad in a "Windows-Latin-1" locale.
   Notepad misreads UTF8 as CP-1252, 
    partly because UTF-8 has no Byte-Order Mark and because
    many Microsoft tools abuse/misuse a Byte-Order Mark as an 
    Encoding indicator.
3. Save file as "Unicode". 
   Notepad uses Microsoft's incorrect terminology and translates
   what it thinks is CP-1252 into UTF-16 little-endian (with BOM)

But that's too easy (so I haven't tried it).

I'm sure the answer will be blindingly obvious in retrospect. But that's small comfort now.

> **... and how to fix it?**

Given that the only disclosed content is the English word `don't` we can deduce that the whole data is [95% ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation_of_English#Frequency). That makes if feasible to use manual inspection ...

1. Make a list of all the different gobbledegook sequences and plausible replacements starting with `0x89dbaa` -> `'`.
2. Use a byte-oriented tool (e.g. `sed`) to make those substitutions.
3. ???
4. Profit!

Comment: Thanks. The file is long and almost all the characters are ASCII and appear correctly. I suppose it might have been opened in Notepad on Windows, but I think it is more likely that it was processed in some other naive way on Windows, e.g. opening and saving in Excel with default or wrong settings. It hasn't been passed around all that much, so I doubt it was wrongly converted more than once. Those assumptions would make the problem a lot simpler than your Rubik's cube analogy, I think. Maybe I will try writing code like you suggest ...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem (FYI - in the Natural Earth data set). I wrote a C# program to find what transformations are applied, and finally I found a path from the curly apostrophe `’` to `‰Ûª`:

- First, encode `’` in UTF-8 (`E2 80 99`).
- Read the three bytes as Windows-1252 (a.k.a. CP1252, Western European (Windows));
  which produces the three characters `â€™`.
- Encode `â€™` in Mac OS Roman (a.k.a. CP10000 on Windows) (`89 DB AA`).
- Again, read the three bytes as Windows-1252; which result in `‰Ûª`.

Thus, to obtain the original text, we can do exactly the reverse:

- First, encode the text in Windows-1252.
- Read the bytes as Mac OS Roman.
- Again, encode the text in Windows-1252.
- Read the bytes as UTF-8.